# Switching databases with LINQ to SQL with proper authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm writing an ASP.NET (VS2013) web app that uses LINQ to SQL. The datacontext is created via the graphical interface and it works great.   I need to switch from DEV to INT and then to PROD programmatically.
sounds simple and after reading many, many  postings I'm super frustrated.

When I switch to DEV it works because the connection already exists. when I switch to INT it fails but NOT because the authentication but because the the Store Procedure doesn't exist...  that makes NO sense...

can anyone please help me with tested statements??? (i already tried lots of "I think...")

----WP_LINQ2SQLDB.DESIGNER.VB----

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Linq
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Reflection


<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name:="WorkOrder")> _
Partial Public NotInheritable Class WP_LinQ2SQLDataContext
    Inherits System.Data.Linq.DataContext

    Private Shared mappingSource As System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource = New AttributeMappingSource()

#Region "Extensibility Method Definitions"
    Partial Private Sub OnCreated()
    End Sub
#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("", mappingSource)
        OnCreated()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal connection As String)
        MyBase.New(connection, mappingSource)
        OnCreated()
    End Sub
```

etc...

----WP_LINQ2SQLDB.VB----

```vb
 Inherits System.Data.Linq.DataContext

    Private Sub OnCreated()

        Dim connectionStr As String = Nothing

        Select Case My.Settings.DB_to_Use
            Case "DEV"
            Case "INT"
                connectionStr = "Data Source=SERVER\DBINST;Initial Catalog=CAT_Order;Integrated Security=True;"
            Case "PRD"
        End Select
        Dim DB_TUAcct = My.Settings.DB_TUAcct
        Dim DB_TUPwd = My.Settings.DB_TUPwd

        connectionStr = connectionStr + "User ID=Domain\blah" + DB_TUAcct.ToUpper + ";Password=" + My.Settings.DB_TUPwd + ";"
```

----DEFAULT.VB----

```vb
' I've tried...  

Dim dc As WP_LinQ2SQLDataContext = New WP_LinQ2SQLDataContext(temp)
Dim dc As WP_LinQ2SQLDataContext = New WP_LinQ2SQLDataContext(builder.ConnectionString)

' building a connection string from sql builder 

Dim builder2 As IDbConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(temp)
dc.Connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
```

BUT at the end of the day, I cannot make the LINQ to fail because the connection string is bad... and I dont know to fix...

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Do you get an error message? If so, please provide full error details

Comment: No error message.  if I change the database, the error is not stored procedure (because it's not there, so that's cool). but the issue is that I need to change the user and I cannot make that work... (the connection works with the original user/pwd)